# Get attr(id) with a known href variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the id name thanks to a href value that is set in a variable.

To do this, I want to:

- get the attr('href') of a clicked element (that works).
- put it in a variable (OK).
- search this href in a every class called ".link" (not in #prev-ajax, #next-ajax id) (problem)
- Get the parent id.

I tried this :

```
$('#prev-ajax,#next-ajax').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".link[href*= href ]:not('#prev-ajax,#next-ajax')");
    var ajax = $(this).parents('.element').attr('id');
    alert(ajax);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using a JavaScript variable, you need to escape the quotes. Also, don't wrap items in the `:not` selector in quotes.

Try this:

```
$(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
```

Edit: Looking at your fiddle, you're also **not doing anything with that selector**. See this:

```
$(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
var ajax = $(this).parents('.element').attr('id');
```

It **should be**:

```
var link = $(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
var ajax = link.parents('.element').attr('id');
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKyT4/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However it still don't work. I will do a fiddle example.

Comment: @lolo Okay just post the link here, curiously you don't actually do anything with that selector, should you be alerting the parent of the result of that selector?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKyT4/2/ . I will use thit id to search other links. I put the code that search the link in the fiddle.

Comment: @lolo Check my edit, and my fiddle for a working demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/UKyT4/1/

Comment: @lolo No problems, if this answer was correct, please click the tick next to it. Welcome to SO!